# Как получить сущности только с 1 связью many-to-many?

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT p0_.id                AS id
FROM product p0_
         LEFT JOIN product_color_group p7_ ON p0_.id = p7_.product_id
         LEFT JOIN color_group c3_ ON c3_.id = p7_.color_group_id
WHERE c3_.id IN (17, 15)
GROUP BY p0_.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c3_.id) = 1
ORDER BY p0_.id ASC
LIMIT 18;
```

В таблице product_color_group только product_id и color_group_id

Нужно показывать товары у которых есть только один из выбранных цветов (или 17 или 15). А запрос возвращает и товары, у которых есть например цвета 17 и 3
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте рассуждать немного более по-программистски. Надо выбрать из таблицы `product_color_group` (внезапно!) только те строки, которые имеют единственное на таблицу `product_id` (только один цвет). Кроме того, в расчёт берём строки только с `color_group_id` = 17 и 15.

Теперь осталось сджойнить это с `product` и `color_group`.

UPD таки просто

```
select
    any_value(`products`.`name`),
    any_value(`colors`.`name`),
    count(`product-colors`.`productId`) as `colorsCount`,
    any_value(`product-colors`.`colorId`) as `colorId`
from `product-colors`
inner join `products` on `products`.`id` = `product-colors`.`productId`
inner join `colors` on `colors`.`id` = `product-colors`.`colorId`
group by `product-colors`.`productId`
having
    `colorsCount` = 1
    and `colorId` in (2, 3)
```

Или вот с подзапросом (просто для красоты)

```
select
    `products`.*,
    `colors`.*
from (
    select
        `productId`,
        any_value(`colorId`) as `colorId`,
        count(`productId`) as `colorsCount`
    from `product-colors`
    group by `productId`
    having
        `colorsCount` = 1
        and `colorId` in (2, 3)
) as `product-colors`
inner join `products` on `products`.`id` = `product-colors`.`productId`
inner join `colors` on `colors`.`id` = `product-colors`.`colorId`
order by `products`.`id`
limit 18;
```

UUPD Подумал ещё. С небольшим лимитом, при большом количестве записей в таблице продуктов будет оптимальнее подзапрос в where.

```
select
    `products`.*,
    `colors`.*
from `products`
inner join `product-colors` on `product-colors`.`productId` = `products`.`id`
inner join `colors` on `colors`.`id` = `product-colors`.`colorId`
where (
    select count(*)
    from `product-colors`
    where `product-colors`.`productId` = `products`.`id`
) = 1
and `colors`.id in (2, 3)
order by `products`.`id`
limit 18;
```

Comment: Нужно  чтобы основной SELECT возвращал товары, поэтому такой вариант не подходит

Comment: @SurenderMeg так inner join и товары у вас.

Comment: @SurenderMeg проблема только в том, что это совсем не оптимальный запрос. Чтобы узнать у каких товаров только один цвет, надо обойти всю таблицу. Если продуктов с одним цветом много, то может быть оптимальнее идти по продуктам и делать подзапросы в where (тогда лимит сработает раньше, чем обойдётся вся таблица). Ещё как вариант, можно добавить продуктам вычисляемое поле количество цветов, например.